# Calculate Euclidean distance of ATMs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby, euclidean-distance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb7AO.png)

I need to group the atms by banks (clean_name) and calculate the distance of each atms within a particular bank and find the max euclidean distance.

not sure how to apply a euclidean function to groupby and output the max euclidean distance

Comment: Can you show some source code you tried? where is the reference point for the euclidean distance? what kind of data do you have? A dataframe?

Comment: import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial
atm_number=df.groupby('clean_name')['objectid'].count()
def not_one_atm(s):
    return atm_number[s]>1
df['more_than_one_atm']=df['clean_name'].map(one_atm)
bank_distance=df[['clean_name','x','y']][df['more_than_one_atm']]
print(bank_distance)
distance_rank=bank_distance.groupby('clean_name').apply(lambda x: spatial.distance.pdist(np.array(list(zip(x.x, x.y)))).max())
distance_rank.sort_values(ascending=False)[0:10]

Comment: I got the answer, but i had to download a package to do the euclidean distance. it just really made no sense to me. my professor is probably asking us to provide a custom aggfunc.

Answer (score 0):

Euclidean is calculated as follows (Run Snippet):

```html
<img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/4febdae84cbc320c19dd13eac5060a984fd438d8" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.671ex; width:35.907ex; height:4.843ex;" alt="{\displaystyle d(\mathbf {p} ,\mathbf {q} )={\sqrt {(q_{1}-p_{1})^{2}+(q_{2}-p_{2})^{2}}}.}">
```

sort the banks name (clean_name) then calculate the distance between bank and it's ATM using above formula.

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure if this is the result you expected. I generated random ATM locations with random ATM names from ATM0 till ATM100.

```
"""Test Values"""
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

atms = {
    'clean_name' : ['ATM'+str(int(round(i*100))) for i in np.random.rand(300)],
    'x': np.random.rand(300)*100000,
    'y': np.random.rand(300)*100000
}
df = pd.DataFrame(atms)
```

I grouped the banks as you did in your comment and waited for a user-Input which ATM is searched:

```
atm_df = df.groupby('clean_name') #Group

"""User-Interface"""
atms = atm_df.groups.keys() #Get all available atm names
atm_name = ''

while atm_name not in atms:
    atm_name = input()

used_atms = atm_df.get_group(atm_name)
print("Used-ATM: {}\nAvailables ATMS: {}".format(atm_name, len(used_atms)))
```

You need to insert the name of the ATM. In my (random) example is the input "ATM10" and the output looks like this:

```
ATM10
Used-ATM: ATM10
Availables ATMS: 3
```

Then we need to get the start-position of the euclidean meassurement (this can be any position with an x and y value)

```
start_pos = {'x': 50000, 'y': 50000}

def euclidean(d_x, d_y, s_x, s_y): 
    return np.sqrt([(d_x-s_x)**2 + (d_y - s_y)**2]).tolist()[0] #euclidean distance function with destination (d) and start (s)
```

Then you calculate the distances and return the maximum value

```
used_atms['distance'] = euclidean(used_atms['x'], used_atms['y'], start_pos['x'], start_pos['y'])
max_atm =  used_atms.loc[used_atms['distance'].idxmax()] #max-distance
```

If you want to illustrate the atms you can follow this source-Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#line from start to destination
lines_x = [start_pos['x'], max_atm['x']]
lines_y = [start_pos['y'], max_atm['y']]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#Plot all Datapoints
ax.scatter(df['x'], df['y'])
ax.scatter(start_pos['x'], start_pos['y'], color='r')
ax.scatter(used_atms['x'], used_atms['y'], color='cyan')

#Plot the line
ax.plot(lines_x, lines_y, color='r')
    
plt.show()
plt.savefig("atms.png")
```

The Result looks like this:

[image]

For further questions. Please be more precise, post your source-Code (reuseable not in comments)